# How to merge multiple arrays in JavaScript with a first elements

Tags: javascript

I have arrays like

```
var arr1=["cat","blue","1"];
var arr2=["cat","red","1"];
var arr3=["cat","yellow","1"];
var arr4=["dog","blue","1"];
var arr5=["dog","red","1"];
```

.
.

I expect a results like

```
var arr1=["cat","blue,red,yellow","1"];
var arr2=["dog","blue,red","1"];
```

Comment: Why would you expect that result? From what you've shown us, you've done nothing...

Comment: Then you'll need to write some code.

Comment: I'd usually set the "set" function to do this in python, but my go to in javascript is usually to iterate over the elements in each array and set them as keys in an object(to remove duplicates), and then recreate the array...does anyone else have any better solutions?

Comment: What is the question? To explain everything is too broad

Comment: It seems that the "Set" data structure has gained mainstream cross browser support since the last time i checked...that's waht you want. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: @AndrewLi ,Scoot Hunter,BrunoLM actually i did somethings with my poor javascript knowledge i tried nested loops but failed to get result and also it was harmful code so i decide to not share at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) data structure.  Create a set with all the arrays you have and you'll have the duplicates removed.
To amend the other user's answer:

```
// Have a single array to loop through.
var mainArray = [];
mainArray.push(["cat", "blue", "1"]);
mainArray.push(["cat", "red", "1"]);
mainArray.push(["cat", "yellow", "1"]);
mainArray.push(["dog", "blue", "1"]);
mainArray.push(["dog", "red", "1"]);

// Result Object.
var resultObject = {};
for (var i = 0; i < mainArray.length; i++) {
  if (!resultObject[mainArray[i][0]]) {
    resultObject[mainArray[i][0]] = [];
  }
  resultObject[mainArray[i][0]] = resultObject[mainArray[i][0]].concat(mainArray[i]);

}



 for (var key in resultObject) {
  if (resultObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    resultObject[key] = new Set(resultObject[key])
    resultObject[key] = Array.from(resultObject[key])
  }
}
console.log(resultObject)
```

Comment: What's the browser support?

Comment: seems pretty legit, except for IE, which has been replaced by edge.

Comment: Oops. Sorry! `:P`

Answer (score 0):

I would first do something like:

```js
// Have a single array to loop through.
var mainArray = [];
mainArray.push(["cat", "blue", "1"]);
mainArray.push(["cat", "red", "1"]);
mainArray.push(["cat", "yellow", "1"]);
mainArray.push(["dog", "blue", "1"]);
mainArray.push(["dog", "red", "1"]);

// Result Object.
var resultObject = {};
for (var i = 0; i < mainArray.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j < mainArray[i].length; j++) {
    if (!resultObject[mainArray[i][0]])
      resultObject[mainArray[i][0]] = [];
    if (resultObject[mainArray[i][0]].indexOf(mainArray[i][j]) == -1)
      resultObject[mainArray[i][0]].push(mainArray[i][j]);
  }
}

// Check it out.
console.log(resultObject);
```

My resultant object will be of the form:

```
{
  "cat": [
    "blue",
    "1",
    "red",
    "yellow"
  ],
  "dog": [
    "blue",
    "1",
    "red"
  ]
}
```

You may ask me if you have any questions in the comments. If you still want it in your original form, you can do so by:

```js
var myObj = {
  "cat": [
    "blue",
    "1",
    "red",
    "yellow"
  ],
  "dog": [
    "blue",
    "1",
    "red"
  ]
};
var myArr = [];
for (var key in myObj) {
  myArr.push([key, myObj[key].join(",").replace(",1", ""), "1"]);
}
console.log(myArr);
```

This gives you:

```
[
  [
    "cat", "blue,red,yellow", "1"
  ],
  [
    "dog", "blue,red", "1"
  ]
]
```